# how to submit a latex article to pattern recognition letters journal

Tags: latex, tex, pdflatex, miktex

the available upload options are

[image]

and what i uploaded are

[image]

[image]

but what i get is not a pdf file after submission, but it's latex tags, it is similar to:

[image]

what am i missing? i've uploaded all .sty, .bst, .bib, .tex, .png files in the folder:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi to all finally i submitted successfully by the following order
don't forget to upload the Highlights as a separate file
[image]

Answer (score 3):

How about reading the [Guide for Authors](https://www.elsevier.com/journals/learning-and-instruction/0959-4752/guide-for-authors) on the Elsevier website and/or the `prletters-template-with-authorship.pdf` file you have there?

Upload only the `.tex` files and the figures, and include the `.bbl` directly into the `.tex` file (typically these submission systems like that better).

Finally, from your screenshot it seems that the journal submission system does not like .`png`s. You should convert them to TIFF or EPS (or any other standard format) that is suggested in the submission information to authors.